# File exist returns true while file delete returns false (Laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, laravel

Working in laravel 5.3 and want to delete file in case of error here is my code

```
if(File::exists($file_destination.$file_name)){
    echo "exists";
    dd(File::delete($file_destination.$file_name));
}else{
    dd('File is not exists.');
}
```

It prints **exists** and false for delete

I also try to use **Unlink method** but in that case it gives error **permission denied** 
Please help to fix thanks

Comment: What if it is folder? `File::exists` calls `file_exists` which returns true if path is also a folder. You cannot delete folder if you don't have permissions or files are inside.

Comment: Have your permissions are correct to delete file from storage ?

Comment: how check about permissions @SagarGautam

Comment: @tilz0R yes file is in a folder

Comment: Are you using windows or linux ? if windows you should not have permission issues but in linux you need read write permission to file

Comment: `ls -la` if you are working on linux

Comment: @SagarGautam i am using windows

Comment: @PatrykUszyński i am using windows

Comment: @bluemoon if folder has files inside, first delete files inside or find laravel recursive delete if exists. Otherwise, if you don't have permissions, you can't do pretty much nothing.

Comment: @tilz0R so how can i give permission to delete file

Comment: @bluemoon  server setup must be correct.

Comment: @tilz0R i am using same method on different places that is working fine but issue is here

Comment: What value is behind `$file_destination.$file_name`?

Comment: What is the output of $file_destination.$file_name

Comment: @PatrykUszyński it is path to file

`"C:\wamp64\www\school-laravel\assets/files/imports/subscribers/Test-file.csv"`

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd it is path to file `"C:\wamp64\www\school-laravel\assets/files/imports/subscribers/Test-file.csv"`

Comment: You have problem with \ and / on your path i think

Comment: then why true on method file::exists() ? @SagarGautam

Comment: The error *"permission denied"* explains why the deletion fails, no matter how do you want to do it.

Comment: @bluemoon In linux, such path will give error, I've not used laravel in windows before

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

This solution may be work for you and I think `$file_name = assets/files/imports/subscribe‌​rs/Test-file.csv`

```
if(file_exists(url('/').$file_name)){

 unlink(base_path('assets/files/imports/sub‌​scribers/'.$file‌​_name));

}
```

Comment: it is not going in if statement

Comment: complete path is as "C:\wamp64\www\school-laravel\assets/files/imports/subscribe‌​rs/Test-file.csv"

Comment: @bluemoon Please display $filename value

Comment: @bluemoon assets folder must be inside your public/ directory for above code to work

Comment: @bluemoon i think your problem with path

Comment: my asset folder is outside public. I don't think so it is a path problem because file::exists() returns true

Comment: $file_name is the name of file suppose test.csv

Comment: @bluemoon Just wait let me check it

Comment: Error is as 

> unlink(C:\wamp64\www\school-laravel\assets/files/imports/subscribers/Test-file.csv):
> Permission denied

Comment: @bluemoon Please check my updated answer and its work fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152624/discussion-between-addweb-solution-pvt-ltd-and-blue-moon).